# no dataimport-handler defined (sorl 4.4.0 / Tomcat / Centos)

Tags: tomcat, solr

I have a problem to connect my solr server to my database.
As i could find on this forum, there is a lot of issues like that and apparantly, i just need to add this line in solrconfig.xml to fix it :

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```

The problem is with solr 4.4.0 i don't have /dist/ folder. 
I even don't have .war file anymore.
Any idea ?

Thanks
Vince

Answer (score 0):

I assume from (Tomcat) that you are not using default Solr distribution but some sort of custom install. I suspect that install does not copy all of the jars correctly.

Just download Solr 4.4 from the website and copy the relevant jars to wherever you want on the file system. Then, adjust **lib** directive to use that path. You can use absolute path, instead of relative one too.

Comment: Well acutally, there isno jars in solr 4.4, at least the one which handle data import

Comment: I see */solr-4.4.0/dist/solr-dataimporthandler-4.4.0.jar* in my distribution that I downloaded from the Apache website. Do you not see it in yours? Are you sure you are downloading the right distribution (specifically not the source one).